# AWS Powershell function converts AWSCredentials to System.Object

Tags: powershell, amazon-web-services

I have a small wrapper function which just passes a couple of variables to the New-Ec2Tag function. When I run it, it coverts my **Amazon.Runtime.AWSCredentials**
into **System.Object[]** and then tries to convert it back and generates an error.

Is there a way to make this function work?

Function

```
function addTag ($awscred, $instanceID, $TagName, $TagValue){
    Write-output $awscred.gettype()
    New-Ec2Tag -region 'ap-southeast-2' -Resource $instanceID -Tag @{Key=$TagName;Value=$TagValue} -Credential $AwsCredentials}
```

Command I run

```
write-output $AwsCredentials.gettype()
addTag($AwsCredentials,$instanceid,"Creator","123456")
```

Command output

```
IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType                                                                                                                       
-------- -------- ----                                     --------                                                                                                                       
True     False    SessionAWSCredentials                    Amazon.Runtime.AWSCredentials                                                                                                  
True     True     Object[]                                 System.Array    

New-EC2Tag : Cannot convert 'System.Object[]' to the type 'Amazon.Runtime.AWSCredentials' required by parameter 'Credential'. Specified method is not supported.
```

The command works if I don't wrap it in a function

```
New-Ec2Tag -region 'ap-southeast-2' -Credential $AwsCredentials -Resource $instanceID -Tag (@{Key="Name";Value="test"})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call your function like this instead:

`addTag $AwsCredentials $instanceid "Creator" "123456"`

In Powershell, function parameters are not called using parenthesis and commas, that's why your parameters are being cast into an Object array.